# Error en select con livewire y laravel error: Attempt to read property "id" on string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, livewire

Tengo un problema haciendo un select con Livewire  y Laravel , me da el siguiente error:

version de laravel Laravel Framework 10.17.0
la version de livewire "livewire/livewire": "^2.11",

y me da error cuando cargo datos en la tabla del select, si no cargo nada, me carga la pagina y hasta la primera opcion del select,

no se donde puede estar el error ayuda!!

adunto el codigo :

Attempt to read property "id" on string

este es mi controlador:

```
    public function render()
    {
      
        return view('livewire.cliente-form', 
        [
            'gruposclientes' => GruposCliente::pluck('descripcion', 'id')
        ]
        );
    }
```

la vista es la siguiente :

````
 <div>
                <label for="gruposclientes" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Grupo de Cliente</label>
                        
                <select wire:model="cliente.gruposclientes" id="gruposclientes" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
                    
                        <option value="null" disabled>{{ __('Please select') }}</option>
                        @foreach($gruposclientes as $gruposcliente)
                            <option value="{{ $gruposcliente->id }}" > {{ $gruposcliente->descripcion }}></option>
                         @endforeach

                </select>
            </div>
    ``` 

el Modelo es asi: 

`
            public function render()
            {
            
                return view('livewire.cliente-form', 
                [
                    'gruposclientes' => GruposCliente::pluck('descripcion', 'id')
                ]
                );
            }
````

y la migracion es asi, hice una migracion de clientes agregandole la columna de gruposclientes_id que no estaba creada.

```
        Schema::table('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('gruposclientes_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->after('email')
                ->constrained()
                ->nullOnDelete();

                $table->foreign('gruposclientes_id')->references('id')->on('clientes');
        });
    }

   

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropConstrainedForeignId('gruposclientes_id');
        });

        Schema::dropIfExists('grupos_clientes');
    }
```

el error que me aparece es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo, cree un componente select re-usable

cree un nuevo componente a partir del input text de jetstreaen resources/views/components

```
@props([
            'disabled' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Select',
            'options' => []
            ])

            <select {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {!! $attributes->merge(
                    ['class' => 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 
                    block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 
                    dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500']) !!}>
                <option value="">{{ $placeholder }}</option>
                @foreach($options as $id => $label)
                <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $label }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

y en el formulario queda asi:

```
<div>
            <label for="tipoclientes" :value="__('tipoclientes')" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Grupo de Cliente</label>
                    
            <x-select id="tipoclientes" wire:model="cliente.tipocliente_id"  class="mt-1 block w-full" :options="$tipoclientes" id="tiposclientes" :placeholder="__('Select tipocliente')"  />
            <x-input-error for="tipoclientes" class="mt-2" />
        </div>
```

el controlador de livewire lo modifiqué de esta manera

```
        <?php

    namespace App\Http\Livewire;

    use App\Models\Cliente;
    use App\Models\TipoCliente;
    use Livewire\Component;

    class ClienteForm extends Component
    {
        
        public Cliente $cliente ;
        
    
        protected $rules = [
            'cliente.razonsocial' => ['required', 'min:4', 'max:200'],
            'cliente.rif' => ['required'],
            'cliente.telefono' => ['nullable'],
            'cliente.direccion' => ['required'],
            'cliente.email' => ['required','min:3','email'],
            'cliente.tipocliente_id' => [],


        ];

        public function mount(Cliente $cliente)
        {
            $this->cliente = $cliente;
        }

        public function updated($propertyName)
        {
            $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
        }
        

        public function save()
        {
    
            $this->validate();

        $this->cliente->save();
            
            session()->flash('status', ('Cliente Guardado.'));

            $this->redirectRoute('clientes.lista');
        }


                public function render()
                {
                
                    return view('livewire.cliente-form', 
                    [
                        'tipoclientes' => TipoCliente::pluck('descripcion', 'id')
                    ]
                    );
                }
    }
```